# Detect collision in circle and destroy other car unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a car multiplayer game and i want if the player 1 and player2 is in circle and the other players (player 3,4,5) are outside the circle then the outside players (player 3,4,5)  destroy and the circle players (player 1,2) won.. I dont understand hows it possible

I use ontrigger but i dont understand how can I apply this

Comment: what have you acheived so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question, as it is presented now, is too broad and does not attend to the guidelines of this website. Questions should ask a specific question, show some code progress and expected result (see [ask] and [tour]). I suggest you instead to look for an introductory Unity tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Well with the limited knowledge of your project, the best advice I can give is have a collider for that circle, make it a trigger, and make a Collision script for it where you have the following method

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name(or tag) == "Whatever the tag or name you want")
    {
        // check here for some field or identifier for the specific instance 
        // of the object to see which player entered the circle
        carMasterScript.DestroyEverythingExcept(other);
    }
}
```

Once you replace the vague things here with what you have in your scripts, and possibly make some Master script so you can have a single instance that can reach and access every car/player instance, this should trigger when another trigger object(make the cars trigger rigidbodies or kinematic bodies as well) and check to see if the thing that collided is a car, then protects that instance of the car while destroying every other one

Comment: Alternatively you could use OnCollisionEnter, which is similar but doesn't use triggers so you could avoid having to make the semblance of physics and gravity, but it would also act like a wall and things wouldn't be able to pass through it. All your choice though of course

Comment: I am working on a car multiplayer game and i want if the player 1 and player2 is in circle and the other players (player 3,4,5) are outside the circle then the outside players (player 3,4,5) destroy and the circle players (player 1,2) won.. I dont understand hows it possible

I use ontrigger but i dont understand how can I apply this

Comment: On the rigidbody component in the inspector, you can check the "Trigger" option for the players and the circle so that whenever they collide and you have the OnTriggerEnter method, that method will be called and you can do what you want to do there

Comment: For example, both cars are triggers and the circle is too, when one of the cars reaches the collider of the circle, the car will send a trigger to a script on the circle that has the OnTriggerEnter method, which then allows you to check which car entered first, and then you can destroy the other car